# Android:ProgressBar causing AsyncTask to malfunction

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

In my activity, I have to get a large JSON ~600KB using `HttpPost`. This takes some time to download and allocate memory for, so i do it in an `AsyncTask`. I have a `TextView` that simply says loading in my XML:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/loader_tv"
        android:text="@string/loading"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/shipid_tv"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dip"
        android:layout_below="@id/shipid_tv"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
```

When the `AsyncTask` finishes its `doInBackGround`, in `postExecute`, I hide the loading TextView with

```
loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

All this worked perfectly.

Now I commented out the `TextView` and put a `ProgressBar`:

```
           <!-- TextView
                android:id="@+id/loader_tv"
                android:text="@string/loading"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/shipid_tv"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dip"
                android:layout_below="@id/shipid_tv"
                android:textSize="18sp" /-->  

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/loading_pb"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:indeterminate="true"
                android:indeterminateBehavior="repeat"/>
```

And also in the activity class:

```
//TextView loading;
ProgressBar loading;
```

In `onCreate`:

```
//loading=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.loader_tv);
loading=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.loading_pb);
```

and the `loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);` line obviously remains same.

Just doing this makes my program go haywire.

The `ProgressBar` appears, but then the JSON doesn't start downloading. If I wait too long(~1 minute, it never takes more than 5sec) I get an Exception for the connection timing out. It gets weirder, if I press back without waiting so long, it goes back to the previous activity and starts downloading the JSON immediately. I don't understand how the progressbar affects the `doInBackground` part of my code, I've not even mentioned it in that function. I've repeatedly commented the progressbar and put the textview back and vice versa, whenever it's on textview it works fine, when it's on progressbar it doesn't work.

I'm stumped, any solutions?

**EDIT:**

My doInBackGround is as follows:

```
protected JSONObject doInBackground(Void... params){

    String s;
    String keyval=intent_data;
    String orgcode=MainActivity.un.getText().toString();
    JSONObject jsonobj=null, shipmentcodesend=null;
    try{
        jsonobj=new JSONObject("someHeavyJson");
    }
    catch(JSONException je){
        Log.e("ShipmentEventFindingActivity.EventFindAsyncTask","JSON error" , je);
        ErrorDialog displayerror=new ErrorDialog(je, context);
        displayerror.showDialog();
    }

    System.out.println("Made jsonobject");
    System.out.println(jsonobj.toString());

    JSONConnectorPost connector1=new JSONConnectorPost(jsonobj, getString(R.string.PIDsearch_url), MainActivity.cookieStore.getCookies());
    JSONObject result=connector1.connectClient();
    s=result.toString();

    try{
        String cacheID=result.getString("cacheId");
        shipmentcodesend=new JSONObject("andMoreJson");
    }
    catch(JSONException je){
        Log.e("ShipmentEventFindingActivity.EventFindAsyncTask","JSON error" , je);
        ErrorDialog displayerror=new ErrorDialog(je, context);
        displayerror.showDialog();
    }

    System.out.println("Made shipmentcodesend");
    System.out.println(shipmentcodesend.toString());

    JSONConnectorPost connector2=new JSONConnectorPost(shipmentcodesend, getString(R.string.PIDsearch_url),MainActivity.cookieStore.getCookies());
    shipmentcodes=connector2.connectClient();

    return result;
}
```

Comment: post your do asyntask/

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin I was going to at first but it's a bit huge, here I'll post it anyway

Comment: Everything that updates the UI can't be done in doInBackground(). So `displayerror.showDialog();` will cause a crash.

Comment: @WarrenFaith agreed, But it never goes to catch when there is a loading textview, why should it go there and crash when I use a progress bar? And it doesn't even get to that exception, that progressbar just keeps on loading.

Comment: "I get an Exception for the connection timing out" well I would start by fixing that :)

Comment: @WarrenFaith the connection times out because the download doesn't start, why it doesn't start I have no clue. Again, it works fine(download starts and finishes in about 5sec) when there is a TextView instead of a ProgressBar. And I removed all the showDialog()s and still the same.

Comment: There is no valid reason why it should work with a TextView in a layout instead of an ProgressBar. The error must be somewhere else. You could try to download the JSON with Volley or another REST library. I would recommend doing that anyways because inventing the wheel again doesn't make sense :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to have this in your AsyncTask:

```
private final ProgressBar progressBar;
private final TextView textView;
public LoadingTask(TextView textView, ProgressBar progressBar) {
        this.progressBar = progressBar;
        this.textView = textView;
}

@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... params) {
   //Your post request
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    progressBar.setProgress(values[0]); // This is ran on the UI thread so it is ok to update our progress bar ( a UI view ) here
}
```